# How did Sulu know where one is being beamed from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the Star Trek (TOS) episode Shore Leave, how did Sulu know that a crew member was specifically beaming down from the bridge and not from the transporter room?
When Spock is beaming down to the planet, Sulu comments

> “Someone is trying to beam down from the bridge.”

Comment: I expect it's because he read the script

Comment: It's because the packets are labeled with the originating IP address.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, this *appears* to have been an error on the part of the actor (or director) that made it into the final cut. In the show's [novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_12), based on the original screenplays, the line is corrected back to "ship" because obviously Sulu would have no way of knowing who was beaming down from where.

> *The air was shimmering. A familiar shimmer, but erratic and uncertain.
> **“Someone’s beaming down from the ship.”***
>
> *Someone was certainly trying to, but there appeared to be some
> obstruction.*
>
> *Willing the transporter to operate, as if that would do any good, Kirk
> waited. The shimmer faded, erupted, faded; with one last splash of
> sparkles, Spock materialized in front of them.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek 12: James Blish](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_12)</sup></sub>

As to how such an error could have passed off without notice, it's worth looking at what happened on the day. Due to overruns, they had to rush through outdoor scenes in order to still have enough light for the 'samurai fight scene'. They failed, and ended up having to run for an extra four hours in the dark, at considerable cost to the studio.

> So much time was put into the fight, in fact, that there was precious
> little time to shoot the other scene that had to be completed this
> final day on location - Sulu's encounter with the Samurai Warrior.
>
> George Takei said, "I remember us losing the sun. That scene where the
> Samurai soldier leaps out - that was supposed to be daylight. The
> beginning part we shot in daylight, and we had to match it. We were
> shooting that at nine o'clock at night. They brought in all of the
> lights they could to try and simulate daylight. It was really tense."
>
> <sub><sup>[These are the voyages: The filming of Shore Leave](http://www.thesearethevoyagesbooks.com/filming-of-shore-leave.html)</sup></sub>